# When will the computational powers be strong enough to let play big games like Battlefield, COD from cloud?

Tags: online, cloud-computing

Is there any current service similar to Steam but without having to download any games?  In other words, buy digital rights to play and play from the cloud?

How much bandwidth would be necessary to play it **purely** online, and how fast must the network be?

Do you think it will become a reality in near future (for example, in the next 10 years)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Gaming / Gaming on Demand / Game Streaming / Gaming as a Service (GaaS) is an up-and-coming set of technologies that, due primarily to advances in signal compression, do not require the sort of bandwidth one might expect in order to stream a framebuffer, every frame, to a remote client.

[NVIDIA Grid](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cloud-gaming.html) is such a technology.

[Here](http://www.ciinow.com/) is a service provider for cloud gaming.

I'm sure you can find many more online.

Of course the benefit to this is that it is pretty much hack-proof.
The downside is that unless you are in close network proximity to your service provider, lag is a fact of life (which won't bother most, by this stage, especially given extant lag-mitigation mechanisms common in games over the last decade).